# Arduino Pro Mini doesn't automatically reset

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, ftdi

I have an issue with my Arduino pro mini.
Yesterday, I uploaded a sketch a few times on the pro mini, with an FTDI adapter, and everything worked fine. Today I'm trying to re-upload a sketch, but now, for some obscure reasons, my Arduino pro mini doesn't want to reset itself. I need to manually reset it. Since it is embedded in s case, I can't do that if I want to upload a sketch.

**EDIT**: I managed to make some tests, and it would seem that the DTR pin on the mini doesn't work anymore. When I short the DTR PIN to GND, the mini doesn't reset itself. I believe that could be a reason. But why? And how? It was working a day ago.

I soldered the FTDI like that, and it didn't work several times.
(At the moment I left it unsoldered because I don't want to solder it yet):

[image: setup]

Can anyone complete my intuition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solder it? Or did you use a "female" connector soldered? Please [edit] your question and add this information, optimally with an actual picture of _your_ assembly.

Comment: I edited the question, the connection is soldered, but it doesn't work

Comment: You have nothing else connected to the board besides the FTDI adapter? You have selected the "Arduino Pro or Pro Mini" from the standard AVR based Arduino support and not something else (e.g. minicore)?

Comment: No, I have only my FTDI, and I selected "Arduino Pro or Pro Mini" from the standard AVR based Arduino.

Comment: *"When I short the DTR PIN to GND, the mini doesn't reset itself"* if you are doing that with the FTDI adapter still soldered you are either trying doing what the FTDI adapter is already doing (which is of no use) or you are trying to short out DTR by connecting it to ground while FTDI is trying to drive it high (not really a good idea either).

Comment: Well it is of use, to determine if the FTDI or the mini is the problem. I'm not sure if the FTDI isn't sending the signlal, or if the signal isn't reaching the internal Atmega328. And what do you mean by "connecting it to ground while FTDI is trying to drive it high". To reset the arduino, the DTR pin must go low (to GND) ? Or did I badly understood this thread ? : [Mini reset issue](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/351133/326465)

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about this without it turning into a lengthy discussion. At any given moment FTDI chip is internally connecting DTR to either 5V (in your case) or GND. What happens if you jumper DTR to the same thing the FTDI chip is connecting it to? Nothing. It was already connected.  What happens if you connect it to the opposite thing? A large amount of current flows as you attempt to connect 5V and GND to each other through the FTDI's DTR pin. If you did this previously it's not unlikely that this is why your auto-reset no longer works. It is **not** diagnostically useful.

Comment: Well the FTDI chip is **supposed** to be connected to the DTR pin, but I need to make sure it still does (it's a cheap FTDI board btw). If that's wrong do you have any idea of how I could diagnose my board ? Or even solve the problem maybe ? And no **I tried to GND it that after the auto reset wasn't working anymore, it's not the problem**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141412/discussion-between-timemage-and-brucewawe).

Comment: Given your last message in the chat it sounds like this will not be clarified and resolved. If that's the case you should probably delete the question so it is not floating around in the system forever like that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this is an actual photo of your FTDI and mini? I can't tell whether the FTDI pins are soldered to the mini. If not, I would guess that the problem is an unreliable electrical connection at one of the pins, and look there for the problem.

If it helps, this is what I use for my embedded devices. The FTDI is in the USB-A connector. The embedded end is just a female connector that pushes onto the 6 pins on the board. This cable supplies +5v; there are also ones that supply 3.3v.

[image: FTDI Cable]

> Thanks for your answer, the connection is soldered.

In that case, I'd check the resistance of the solder joints including trying to wiggle them; then trying to narrow it down by swapping FTDI boards if you have another; and likewise, swapping the mini board.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the connection is soldered. I don't think it's a connection problem, I verified the soldered connection, tried to bend them, there's nothing to do.
Thanks for you picture, it seems I have the same connections. Really don't know where to look ...

Answer (score 0):

The reset pulse issued by the USB-Serial adapter via the DTR line may be of low amplitude (3.3V). This is occasionally too low for the Pro Mini reset function.  Sometimes, it helps to solder a 47k resistor across the reset button contacts, lowering the initial DC level of the reset input. This applies to 5V/16MHz and 3.3V/8MHz versions of the Pro Mini.